# Add non occurent factors to data frame in R

Tags: r, r-factor

I have a dataframe of factors and corresponding values like this:

```
df <- data.frame(week = factor(c(1,2,49,50)), occurrences = c(1,4,2,3))


 week occurrences
1    1          1
2    2          4
3   49          2
4   50          3
```

I want to add factors for all the "missing" weeks in (1-53) with the corresponding occurrences value of  0. What is the best way to do this? I have to do this to several data frames that may not be "missing" the same factors so I would like to generalize it in a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `rbind()` to append the necessary lines to your `df`, in this example, I first create the df to be added before appending it for clarity. `setdiff()` will return the numbers currently not present in your week column:

```
df_to_app = data.frame(week = factor(setdiff(1:52, df$week)), occurrences = 0)
df = rbind(df, df_to_app)
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks. The setdiff function did the trick

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach with `tidyr::complete`. First, we need to add the additional levels to our `week` column. We can use `forcats::fct_expand`. Then `tidyr::complete` will fill the data.frame with those levels and we can use the `fill =`  argument to indicate that we want `0`.

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  mutate(week = fct_expand(week,paste0(1:52))) %>%
  complete(week, fill = list(occurrences = 0))
# A tibble: 52 x 2
   week  occurrences
   <fct>       <dbl>
 1 1               1
 2 2               4
 3 49              2
 4 50              3
 5 3               0
 6 4               0
 7 5               0
 8 6               0
 9 7               0
10 8               0
# … with 42 more rows
```

Or with a right join to a data.frame containing all weeks:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   right_join(data.frame(week = as.factor(1:52))) %>%
    mutate(occurrences = replace_na(occurrences,0))
```

Comment: Thanks. Used the other answer but this seems to work to :)